# Using the find utility within a simple function in .bashrc does not work. Why?

Tags: bash, find

I'm using the latest arch kernel 5.7.12-arch1-1, the latest bash version 5.0.017-1 and the latest coreutils-8.32-1 which the find utility is a part of.

I have the following code in my `.bashrc` to make easy work of finding files on the system.

But I can't quite get it working.

At the bash command prompt the following all produce the correct output, listing the correct files I wish to locate
`find . -iname '*driving*licence*part*'`
`find . -iname '*driving*licence'`
`find . -iname '*driving*'`

So why does
`f driving licence part`
`f driving licence`
`f driving`
using the below function not?

Each `if` statement is parsing for the number of variables provided.

```
function f () {
     
     # find files
     
     # update the files location database 
     sudo updatedb


    if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ] && [ -n "$3" ]; then  
     find . -iname '*$1*$2*$3*'
    fi

    if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]; then  
     find . -iname '*$1*$2*'
    fi

    if [ -n "$1" ]; then  
     find . -iname '*$1*'
    fi


}
```

Comment: Variables are not expanded within single quotes.

Comment: I have solved it with the help of the linked question. But that was not the whole story. The issue was `if` statement structure. I had tried the `"*${1}*"` expansion, as the provided link suggests, & abandoned it becasue I got confused. The confusion occured becasue my if statement structure was concatenating three different `find` results as all the `if` statements were being applied. I used `elif` in place of `if` with  `"*${1}*"` expansion and the function now works as intended. As such the reasons given above for this being a duplicate question are not full & it may well not be a duplicate

Comment: The immediate issue that you had with your code was the issue of quoting using single quotes. That was what the question was about. The issue relating to the logic of the `if` statements was not a problem that you had, but a follow-up issue that you noticed when you corrected the primary quoting issue. I'd suggest that you ask a new modified question about the `if` statements (with the quoting issue corrected).

Comment: `find` doesn't use the database that `updatedb` updates. That database is for the `locate` command.

Comment: Here, you could just do `f() (IFS=*; exec find . -iname "*${*}*")`. Or in `zsh`: `f() find . -iname "*${(j[*])argv}*"`

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas "find doesn't use the database that updatedb updates. That database is for the locate command". Some links suggest it does. Which command updates the find db?

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas this from you `f() (IFS=*; exec find . -iname "*${*}*"). Or in zsh: f() find . -iname "*${(j[*])argv}*"` is a geat solution.

Comment: `find` accesses the file system directly, reads the directory contents and `lstat()`s the files, it doesn't rely on a separate db (though I suppose you could say that the filesystem is itself a database)